# Как импортировать множество файлов в confluence?

Tags: confluence

У нас появился `confluence` для ведения информации по проекту. Хочу в `confluence` завести ветку по базе данных, в которой разместить структуру БД. Я могу автоматом генерировать набор страниц(например в `html` или в другом формате), ссылающихся друг на друга.

Как можно все это дело импортировать в `confluence` с сохранением работоспособности ссылок?

Альтернативный вариант менять ссылки руками, но это довольно неудобно и делать этого не хочется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На текущий момент в `Confluence` нет инструмента для импорта иерархии страниц из внешнего источника.

Здесь перечислены все возможные варианты: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/import-content-into-confluence-191141.html

- Импорт из другого экземпляра `Confluence` сайта целиком или отдельного раздела (по сути восстановление бекапа)
- [Импорт из документа Word](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/import-a-word-document-into-confluence-170493136.html)
- Импорт HTML страницы (можно включить код внешней HTML страницы в страницу `Confluence` или сгенерировать свой HTML код)

Также можно попробовать реализовать свой собственный скрипт импорта с использованием REST API: https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples